# MediaWiki: What are parameters in widgets?

Tags: html, mediawiki

**I'd like to add some HTML code to all pages of a MediaWiki website**,
for that I've installed the [Widgets extension by documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets#Installation),

I understand that I should create the widget code **as a wiki page** and then call it with the `{{#widget}}` parser function,
but I miss what are the parameters there in call as it's just HTML I call to insert between `<head></head>`:

```
{{#widget:WidgetName|param1=value1|param2=value2}}
```

What are these parameters and wouldn't it be easier to add some custom JavaScript to add the HTML to each webpage?

Comment: The parameters are explained just a little below where your link points to.

Comment: `param=value pairs are the settable parameters, defined within the widget code` = what they use for? `All parameters passed to a widget are converted into Smarty parameters.` What they use for? I think this is the only indirect explanation I found: `Important: Use escape modifiers on all passed-in parameters to prevent users from passing in raw HTML from normal wiki pages. Failure to protect against this will expose the hosting site to XSS (and other) attacks.`: They hold "pieces" of HTML.